# H2 database string to timestamp

Tags: h2, milliseconds, timestamp

### Insertion of timestamps in H2 database

Hello, I have to insert data like '17-09-2012 18:47:52.69'. Function PARSEDATETIME cuts milliseconds.
Query example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID NUMBER(19) not null,
DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO TEST (ID, DATE) VALUES(1,
parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS'))
```

After SELECT I see that milliseconds are zeroes.

What is solution?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to my test, with H2 version 1.3.170, the milliseconds are not actually zero, but 069:

```
select * from test;
ID  DATE  
1   2012-09-17 18:47:52.069
```

The same happens if you run:

```
call parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.69', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS');
```

If you add a zero then it works:

```
call parsedatetime('17-09-2012 18:47:52.690', 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SS');
```

H2 internally uses `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, so it has to live with the same limitations. If you find a solution within `SimpleDateFormat`, you can use it within the `parsedatetime` function in H2.

An alternative is to use the ISO timestamp format as defined in JDBC. This is supposed to work with all databases that conform the JDBC standard:

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(2, {ts '2012-09-17 18:47:52.69'});
```