# Invalid DateTimeFormat when inserting date in H2 in memory DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, date-format

I'm having a problem trying to insert values in a in-memory H2 DB.

I have this Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="myTable")
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "startDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss")
    private Date startDate;
    
    @Column(name = "endDate")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss")
    private Date endDate;
}
```

I've used the pattern `yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss` because the dates are in format like `2021-06-14-00.00.00` or `2021-12-31-23.59.59`.

The `@DateTimeFormat` imported is `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;` and `Date` is `java.util.Date`.

To insert values in the DB I've this script:

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES
(1, '2020-08-07-00.00.00', '2021-12-31-23.59.59'),
(2, '2020-04-03-14.00.00', '2021-01-14-18.30.00'),
(3, '2020-09-15-00.00.00', '2021-06-15-11.00.00'),
(4, '2020-01-18-16.00.00', '2021-12-31-23.59.59');
```

But it throw an error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Imposible interpretar la constante "TIMESTAMP" "2021-12-31-23.59.59"
Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "2021-12-31-23.59.59"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, ...

...

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: 31-23.59.59
```

The text in the error which is not in english is something like "Unable to interpret constant "TIMESTAMP"".

Also I have tested a few things and, (this is important!) **removing hours, minutes and seconds, the program works**, so I assume is the pattern which is not correct.

This SQL script works:

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES
(1, '2020-08-07', '2021-12-31'),
(2, '2020-04-03', '2021-01-14'),
(3, '2020-09-15', '2021-06-15'),
(4, '2020-01-18', '2021-12-31');
```

I've checked a [DateTimeFormat tester online](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/#) and the current date with my pattern is `2021-12-21-17.44.32`, but even creating the table using only that date it thrown the error.

More info about the table:
The table (and also the columns) is created using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` so I assume the column type is `DATE` (as the entity field).

So I'm trying to insert a String with format `yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss` in a `DATE` column (if I'm not wrong).

So, what's the problem? Is not possible to insert this pattern as date from string in an H2 in memory DB?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please try [`@Temporal`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Temporal.html).. We assume  `java.util.Date`!??;)

Comment: Yes, is `java.util.Date`. How should I use `@Temporal`? I've tried using `@Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)`, also `.TIME` and `.TIMESTAMP` but the error is still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not the JPA layer defined in your Java code but the scripts that you execute.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES
(1, '2020-08-07-00.00.00', '2021-12-31-23.59.59'),
(2, '2020-04-03-14.00.00', '2021-01-14-18.30.00'),
(3, '2020-09-15-00.00.00', '2021-06-15-11.00.00'),
(4, '2020-01-18-16.00.00', '2021-12-31-23.59.59');
```

This has nothing to do with how you have defined your JPA layer. For that script when executed the `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss")` is completely unknown that you have defined in your code.

This is just a script executed in DB. How would the DB know how to convert this String into a valid Date object? You must inform in your script how the conversion from String to Date must happen.

The following should work as the `PARSEDATETIME` is the function for H2 for that reason.

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES (1, PARSEDATETIME('2020-08-07-00.00.00','yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss'), PARSEDATETIME('2021-12-31-23.59.59','yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss')
```

Please also check closely what you execute `yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss`. `yyy` does not conform with the ages that you place in the scripts ex 2020. This is `yyyy`

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

#### Little late but still:)

Assuming (h2, in-mem):

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable(Id NUMBER primary key,START_DATE TIMESTAMP,END_DATE 
TIMESTAMP);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, START_DATE, END_DATE) VALUES
```

like:

```sql
(1, {ts '2020-08-07 00:00:00'}, {ts '2021-12-31 23:59:59'}),
```

(with standard time format)

Or:

```sql
(2, parsedatetime('2020-04-03-14.00.00', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss'), 
    parsedatetime('2021-01-14-18.30.00', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss'));
```

(a custom one)

Refs:

- https://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#date_time
- [H2 database string to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14138532/592355)

Comment: I've tested using `PARSEDATETIME(...)` and works nice, thanks also for the other way using `{ts '...'}.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to insert a `java.util.Date` into a `TIMESTAMP` column you don't need `@DateTimeFormat`. You are not parsing anything, you part from the `Date` object, and JPA translates it into the proper SQL datatype.

Define the column this way:

```
    @Column(name = "startDate")
    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;
```

And you should be good to go.

**Update**

If only `DATE` pattern works, and no `TIMESTAMP` patterns work, it means that the column has been defined with the wrong datatype. DATE and TIMESTAMP are two different H2 datatypes (and in all the other DDBBs but may be with different names)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've tried this but still not work. The column is created using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` so I assume is `DATE` (as the entity field). So I'm trying to insert a String with format `yyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss` in a `DATE` column if I'm not wrong.

Comment: In a DATE column, without the `@DateTimeFormat`, and with `@Temporal(value=TemporalType.DATE)` doesn't work? What is the exception? Because the java.lang.NumberFormatException can only happen if you use `@DateTimeFormat`

Comment: Yes, it throw a  `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. I've checked and there is not any `@DateTimeFormat` in the entity. Maybe is formatted under the hook and that's why the exception is thrown?